# Output both bins and labels column in pandas binning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a dataframe column on which I would like to perform binning, for example:

```
df.head
X
4.6
2.5
3.1
1.7
```

I want one column for the bin range and one column for the label, as follows:

```
df.head
X bin label
4.6 (4,5] 5
2.5 (2,3] 3
3.1 (3,4] 4
1.7 (1,2] 2
```

Apparently, setting the `label` parameter as follows would just result in a column for bin labels, but not for the range anymore.

```
df['bin'] = df.X.apply(pd.cut, labels=np.arange(5))
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this instead of running `pd.cut` 2 times for the 2 columns?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example set of data and code that shows us what you're working with and what you've tried? Here are some tips on creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowing `pd.cut` to set the bin edges dynamically, you can use the `retbins` flag. From the [`pd.cut` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
retbins: bool, default False
    Whether to return the bins or not. Useful when bins is provided as a scalar.
```

This will return a second result:

```
bins: numpy.ndarray or IntervalIndex.
    The computed or specified bins. Only returned when
    retbins=True. For scalar or sequence bins, this is
    an ndarray with the computed bins. If set
    duplicates=drop, bins will drop non-unique bin. For
    an IntervalIndex bins, this is equal to bins.
```

You can use this to assign the bin edges to the frame:

```py
assignments, edges = pd.cut(df.X, bins=5, labels=False, retbins=True)
df['label'] = assignments
df['bin_floor'] = edges[assignments]
df['bin_ceil'] = edges[assignments + 1]
```

Your comments indicate that you'd like to use this within a groupby operation. In that case, you can wrap the above in a function:

```py
def assign_dynamic_bin_ids_and_labels(
    df,
    value_col,
    nbins,
    label_col='label',
    bin_floor_col='bin_floor',
    bin_ceil_col='bin_ceil',
):
    assignments, edges = pd.cut(
        df[value_col], bins=5, labels=False, retbins=True
    )

    df[label_col] = assignments
    df[bin_floor_col] = edges[assignments]
    df[bin_ceil_col] = edges[assignments + 1]

    return df

df.groupby('id').apply(assign_dynamic_bin_ids_and_labels, 'X', 5)
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know what the bin edges are before I perform the `pd.cut`, so I don't have such array as `bin_labels`. In my actual implementation, the binning is performed conditioned on the index, so my code looks like this: `df['bin'] = df.groupby('id').X.apply(pd.cut, bins=5)`. Since there are numerous `id`'s I can't possibly know the bins for each individual `id`'s beforehand.

Comment: I see. This is a super important part of your question. Thanks for the modification to your question!

Comment: You can't even call pd.cut the way you have it written in your question. Can you modify the question to reflect your actual use case?

Comment: @ccying I've modified my answer to reflect your comments.